# list view button show/populate account name

Tags: javascript, list-view, url

when click on the new contact button (this is list view javascript custom button) page redirected but account name not populated automatically

```
    var qc = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType ='" + "Contact" + "'" +" AND DeveloperName = '"+"Suppliers"+ "'"); 

    var qc_records = qc.getArray("records"); 

    var qc_rec = qc.records.Id; 

    var qc1 = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType ='" + "Contact" + "'" +" AND DeveloperName = '"+"Employee"+ "'"); 

    var qc_records1 = qc1.getArray("records"); 

    var qc_rec1 = qc1.records.Id; 
    if('{! Account.Status__c }' == 'Creditor' ||'{! Account.Status__c }' ==   'Debitor' ||'{! Account.Status__c }' == 'Other External' ) 
    { 
    returnUrl = "/003/e?retURL=%2F{! Account.Id }&cancelURL=%2F{! Account.Id}&RecordType="+qc_rec+"&ent=Contact"; 
   } 
     else 
    { 
returnUrl = "/003/e?retURL=%2F{! Account.Id }&cancelURL=%2F{! Account.Id}&RecordType="+qc_rec1+"&ent=Contact"; 

} 
    window.location.href = returnUrl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your return url with this.

```
returnUrl = "/003/e?con4={!Account.Name}&con4_lkid={!Account.Id}&retURL=%2F{! Account.Id }&cancelURL=%2F{! Account.Id}&RecordType="+qc_rec1+"&ent=Contact";
```

Comment: nothing happend

Comment: @cloudZigZag can you try this `returnUrl = "/003/e?con4={!Account.Name}&con4_lkid={!Account.Id}`

Comment: yes i have tried thats why i repied

Comment: @cloudZigZag did this redirect to contact page?

Comment: yes its redirected and now its working actually status not set on account that why not working now its worked thanks